# Using Django Haystack without using Django models

Tags: django, full-text-search, django-haystack

I'm seeking to add fulltext capabilities to a Django application using [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/).

Seems that Haystack can only index and search Django model instances. My fulltext index, however, is over objects that do not live in Django database.

Can I use Haystack to index non-Django objects (documents)? I'm interested in the fulltext engine abstraction layer, but not on the Django model integration.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. Things I'm thinking about are whether I can make an object that acts like a django model so haystack and get the data it needs or over-riding parts of the SearchIndex class to query my data source rather than a django queryset. I can't say if these methods will work yet.

Comment: I considered the first option too, but after some investigation it seemed overkill, and besides it would also require customizations in order to feed the index and keep it up to date. I'd rather go a a bit lower level and do both searching and feeding manually, but I couldn't yet have another look at this. Please do share your findings! :)